# how can i set proxy to my url request in ios

Tags: ios, proxy, uiwebview

i have been trying to set proxy to my request to be loaded in uiwebview, using ASIHTTPRequest but not able to find a solution to it as nothing happens and it just times out.

the code is somewhat like this:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc ] initWithURL:url]; [request setValue:@"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 4_3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile" forKey:@"UserAgent"];
[request setProxyHost:@"proxyaddress"];
[request setProxyPort:@"myportvalue"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Please help me find where i am wrong

Comment: You are aware that `ASIHTTPRequest` has been deprecated for quite some time. It has huge issue on iOS 7 and up. The original developers suggested you move to `AFNetworking`

Comment: @rckoenes i tried it using afnetworking also, but didn't get any solid solution. do you know any other way we can do it.